# How to change just one element of the list view in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, android-listview

I have a listView that returns some Items from Firestore and I want to change the color of just one container when I press over it and change it back when I press again.

How can I do this?

I tried to make a bool and change its value, but that changing the whole items

This is my code:

```
return ListView(

  children: snapshot.data.docs.map<Widget>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
   return Container( child:Text('Hello')

  }).toList();
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create Stateful Widget with your logic. Click on item should change widget state. In this case widget has property like `title` and `isSelected` these properties are wrapped into `ListItem` class. The only logic that you need is basically
`widget._listItem.isSelected = !_isSelected;` in `GestureDetector`. Below example should give you and idea of widget states.

```dart
class SelectableListItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ListItem _listItem;

  const SelectableListItemWidget(this._listItem);

  @override
  _SelectableListItemWidgetState createState() =>
      _SelectableListItemWidgetState();
}

class _SelectableListItemWidgetState extends State<SelectableListItemWidget> {
  String get _title => widget._listItem.title;

  bool get _isSelected => widget._listItem.isSelected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          print('element: $_title has been clicked');
          widget._listItem.isSelected = !_isSelected;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
          color: _isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Text(
            _title,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class ListItem {
  String title;
  bool isSelected;

  ListItem(this.title, {this.isSelected = false});
}
```

New created widget can be used

```dart
  var items = [
    "Apple",
    "Cherimoya",
    "Grapefruit",
    "Jostaberry",
    "Plumcot",
    "Pomegranate",
    "Quince",
    "Kiwi",
    "Kiwano",
    "Huckleberry",
    "Marionberry",
    "Mango",
    "Strawberry",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: items
            .map((item) => SelectableListItemWidget(ListItem(item)))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: flutter selectable listView]

Comment: dude , the array  i have is coming from the FireStore not fixed

Comment: This is just  example, source of items is not important. Instead of `items` use yours `snapshot.data.docs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function `listWidget` on your list of data.

```
List<int> selected = [];
List<Widget> listWidget(List listItems) {
  List<Widget> listWidget = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    var iSeleted = selected.contains(i);
    var temp = GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (iSeleted)
            selected.remove(i);
          else
            selected.add(i);
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        color: iSeleted ? sColor : nsColor,
        child: Text('Hello'),
      ),
    );
    listWidget.add(temp);
  }
  return listWidget;
}
```

Here you can set the `sColor` to the colour you want for selected widget and `nsColor` for not selected widget.

List `selected` will contain the indexes of all the selected items.

Comment: so how to implement this according to my code cause when i call this function and give it the parameter (document ) will give me an error

Comment: You can call this function with the list of docs you have. Something like this:

`List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = snapshot.data.docs;`
`listWidget(docs);`